# Need to link one list to another when sizes different

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, helper

Sorry for the title I can't think of a good way to explain what I need.

I am trying to create an xml file which will be picked up by a system to run through some orders but I am getting stuck on how to create the file correctly.

The file contains:
an order number, each order number can then have multiple order lines, each order line has a product and each product has a quantity.

for example

```
<ORDER="123">
<ORDER_LINE="1" product="abc" QUANTITY="1"/>
<ORDER_LINE="2" product="def" QUANTITY="2"/>
</ORDER>
<ORDER="456">
<ORDER_LINE="3" product="ghi" QUANTITY="3"/>
<ORDER_LINE="4" product="jkl" QUANTITY="4"/>
<ORDER_LINE="5" product="mno" QUANTITY="2"/>
</ORDER>
```

I've written a helper that I want to pass in all the information and then create the xml. The problem is I am confused as to how to determine where 1 order ends and the next begins.

I was going to send all the order ids in a list, all the orderlines in another etc but then I won't know when I get to the end of one order.

In the example above order 123 has 2 products where has order 456 has 3 so it's not a case of just dividing the orderIDs by the rest of the list size.

Can anybody suggest a way I can do this?

I want my helper to be as easy to call as possible and not have to rely on orders being a certain length.

Comment: Show us your code. Its difficult to understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Helper' probably should be a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). I suggest the following API

```
new OderBuilder()
    .startOrder(123) // starts a new order and finishes the first
    .addLineItem("abc",1)
    .addLineItem("def",2)
    .createXml(); // actually writes out the xml or returns it, or what ever you want
```

See key is to create a [fluent API](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) by returning the Builder itself on each method call.

Inside the Builder you might want to create objects for Orders and OrderItems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to point out that your example isn't an xml file: there is no root element and I guess that `<ORDER="123">` and `<ORDER_LINE="3">` are supposed to be something like `<ORDER ID="123">` and `<ORDER_LINE ID="3">`.

Secondly, if I had to create an xml file, I would use the [JAXB library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) and annotations:

I have created a class `Order` that contains all the information about the ORDER (it has a reference to a list of `OrderLine`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Order {

    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    private String id;
    @XmlElement(name="ORDER_LINE")
    private List<OrderLine> orderLineList = new ArrayList<OrderLine>();

    public Order(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<OrderLine> getOrderLineList() {
        return orderLineList;
    }
    public void setOrderLineList(List<OrderLine> orderLineList) {
        this.orderLineList = orderLineList;
    }
    public Order addOrderLine(OrderLine orderLine) {
        orderLineList.add(orderLine);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Then I have created a class `OrderLine` that contains all the information about the ORDER_LINE:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderLine {
    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    private String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name="product")
    private String product;
    @XmlAttribute(name="QUANTITY")
    private String quantity;

    public OrderLine(String id, String product, String quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


}
```

Finally I have created a class `Orders` that will be the root element of my xml file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ORDERS")
public class Orders {

    @XmlElement(name="ORDER")
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public List<Order> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }

    public Orders addOrder(Order order) {
        orderList.add(order);
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Orders orders = new Orders()
            .addOrder(new Order("123")
                .addOrderLine(new OrderLine("1", "abc", "1"))
                .addOrderLine(new OrderLine("2", "def", "2")))
            .addOrder(new Order("456")
                .addOrderLine(new OrderLine("3", "ghi", "3"))
                .addOrderLine(new OrderLine("4", "jkl", "4"))
                .addOrderLine(new OrderLine("5", "mno", "2")));
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Orders.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(orders, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the main method I just create an instance of `Orders` and populate it with the required information. After that I just use methods from the JAXB library.
The output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ORDERS>
    <ORDER ID="123">
        <ORDER_LINE ID="1" product="abc" QUANTITY="1"/>
        <ORDER_LINE ID="2" product="def" QUANTITY="2"/>
    </ORDER>
    <ORDER ID="456">
        <ORDER_LINE ID="3" product="ghi" QUANTITY="3"/>
        <ORDER_LINE ID="4" product="jkl" QUANTITY="4"/>
        <ORDER_LINE ID="5" product="mno" QUANTITY="2"/>
    </ORDER>
</ORDERS>
```

Hope this was helpful.